# How to use current_user for serializer testing in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rspec2, serialization

I am new to rails and serializers.I am using active model serializer gem for serialization.

One of the attributes uses devise helper method 'current_user'.It works fine.But While running the spec using rspec i get an error undefined local variable or method 'current_user'.Please can anyone help me to solve this?

I am using rails 3.2 and rspec 2

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793597/how-to-access-devise-current-user-in-a-rspec-feature-test/28047750#28047750

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but I ran into the same problem, although already using Devise Helpers.

I use Ruby on Rails 4.2, Rspec 3.5, Active Model Serializers 0.8.3.

I have Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers included in Rspec, and can use `sign_in` in my spec file, yet I had `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_user'` when calling the serializer method that relied on `current_user`. Note that the controller use `current_user` fine.

Here is the spec file (not working) :

```
describe ArticleController do
  before :each do 
    @article = create(:article)
  end
  describe 'PUT #update' do
    context "as user" do
      before :each do 
        @u = create(:user)
        sign_in @u
      end

      it 'sets the seen status' do
        put :update, id: @article, article: { seen: true }
        expect(ArticleSerializer.new(@article.reload).seen).to eq(true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the Serializer :

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :text, :seen

  def seen
    object.article_user_seen.find_by( user_id: current_user.id ).try(:seen) || false
  end

end
```

I modified the test, using options `scope` and `scope_name` when creating the serializer instance. Thanks to this guide : https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/serializers.md

Working test below :

```
describe ArticleController do
  before :each do 
    @article = create(:article)
  end
  describe 'PUT #update' do
    context "as user" do
      before :each do 
        @u = create(:user)
        sign_in @u
      end

      it 'sets the seen status' do
        put :update, id: @article, article: { seen: true }
        expect(ArticleSerializer.new(@article.reload, scope: @u, scope_name: :current_user).seen).to eq(true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

first you should  inlcdue `include Devise::TestHelpers` in your rspec file , then you should create a user  and sign in it . like this code :

`@user = create(:user)`

`sign_in @user`

Comment: Now it shows Failure/Error: sign_in @user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass