# How to access (devise) current_user in a rspec feature test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

In the devise documentation they give tips on how you can have access to current_user when testing a controller:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29

However, what about when doing a feature test? I am trying to test a create method of one of my controllers, and in that controller is used the current_user variable.

The problem is that the macro suggested in devise uses the @request variable, and it is nil for a feature spec. What is a workaround?

EDIT:

This is what I have so far for my current spec:

```
feature 'As a user I manage the orders of the system' do
  scenario 'User is logged in ad an admin' do
    user = create(:user)
    order = create(:order, user: user)
    visit orders_path
    #Expectations
  end
end
```

The problem is that in my `OrdersController` I have a `current_user.orders` call, and since `current_user` is not defined, it will redirect me to `/users/sign_in`.

I have defined this under `/spec/features/manage_orders.rb`

Comment: I've used https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access for something like that

Comment: Also, see http://blog.pixarea.com/2013/01/making-rspec-feature-specs-easy-with-devise and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865555/how-to-do-integration-testing-with-rspec-and-devise-cancan.

Comment: Maybe include the test code you are trying to write? You can just pretend that `current_user` is there, I think that will help a lot in clarifying your intentions.

Comment: I am not logging the user because I don't know how to do that in a feature rspec test.

Answer (score 35):

from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29

if i have understood you right, maybe you need to use

```
subject.current_user.email
#or
controller.current_user.email
```

for example :

```
describe OrdersController, :type => :controller do
  login_user

  describe "POST 'create'" do
     it "with valid parametres" do
        post 'create', title: 'example order', email: subject.current_user.email
     end
  end
end
```

controller_macros.rb :

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

Don't forget to include this into your spec_helper.rb :

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
```

Comment: Simply this worked for me: subject.current_user.email

Comment: where to put the controller_macros.rb ?
In spec/support folder ?

Comment: @aldrien.h yes.

Comment: @Hommer Smith this is the correct answer. I tested it too and it works. If it is accepted it will show up on the search query as solved.

Comment: This answer along with that devise wiki page is for controller specs. The question was about feature specs; and devise has a separate page for that: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

feature 'As a user I manage the orders of the system' do
  scenario 'User is logged in ad an admin' do
    user = create(:user)
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
    order = create(:order, user: user)
    visit orders_path
    #Expectations
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer so far as it is very close to the officially recommended way on the devise wiki for feature specs (not controller specs) https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Answer (score 2):

you can define login_user as a method for the user to login as follows (put it in support folder):

```
def login_user
  Warden.test_mode!
  user = create(:user)
  login_as user, :scope => :user
  user.confirmed_at = Time.now
  user.confirm!
  user.save
  user
end
```

Then in the scenario say:

```
user = login_user
```